How to allow _inplacevar_ operations in RestrictedPython?
Expressions such as:
total_impact += impact

in my restricted env are not allowed by default and they cause the error:

NameError: name '_inplacevar_' is not defined

but I would like to allow such expressions. Is there anything that I can add to the restricted globals to allow it? Anything in RestrictedPython.Guards or RestrictedPython.Eval? I can't find it so far

Can't you just write total_impact = total_impact + impact?

This looks like a bug, not a deliberate restriction. The code contains the following comment: Note that although augmented assignment of attributes and subscripts is disallowed, augmented assignment of names (such as 'n += 1') is allowed.

@Barmar I can do the total_impact = total_impact + impact , but imagine having to explain this to users of a coding competition platform. I'd rather just alow in-place operations. I don't completely understand the context of your second comment

As I said, it looks like a bug. When it parses the in-place assignment, it uses that function internally, but it doesn't exist, so you get an error.

Note that it's supposed to restrict variable[index] += and variable.attribute +=. Only variable += is supposed to be allowed.

Yeah, that makes sense. Maybe I should re-try with different versions of the library
